# Route not found after adding 'auth:api' middleware Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to do an api call from one of my laravel projects to another using the new oauth2 feature in laravel 5.3.

I have this route in the api.php route file of my new laravel project that I want to call from the old one:

```
Route::get('/hello', function() {
    return 'hello';
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Without the middleware I can call it without a problem, with the middleware, it throws a 404 not found error.

Here is the code that retrieves the access token and then makes the api call:

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://my-oauth-project.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' => 'client_id',
        'client_secret' => 'client_secret',
    ],
]);
$token = json_decode($response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];

$response = $http->get('http://my-oauth-project.com/api/hello', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
    ],
]);
return $response->getBody();
```

The error that is returned:

```
[2016-10-14 09:46:14] local.ERROR: exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `GET http://my-oauth-project.com/api/hello` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow (truncated...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middleware 'auth:api' automatically redirects the request to a login page (which in this case doesn't exist, hence the 404 error).

The client credentials grant doesn't require a login. The documentation for it hasn't been published yet but the middleware [does exist](https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/34).

To use it create a new middleware under the `$routeMiddleware` variable in `app\Http\Kernel.php` like so:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'client_credentials' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class,
];
```

Then add this middleware onto the end of the route:

```
Route::get('/hello', function() {
    return 'hello';
})->middleware('client_credentials');
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: I can't imagine that the middleware the docs say to use would break for something the docs cover extensively (client creds and password grants). Regardless, thanks for finding this!