# Laravel session based auth:api middleware not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I tried using the Auth Scaffolding of Laravel 5.3 including the api routes. I wanted to use the session driver for the api guard, but apparently this has no impact whatsoever. After I log into the application with a valid user (so I get from `/login` to `/home`) I tried entering the path `/api/user`, but it always redirects me to `/home`. The `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware redirects the user.

Here is what I tried and a quick overview of the test application:

```
// In "app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php"
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

`$guard` is null, and the if is true when browsing to `/api/user`.

```
// In "config\auth.php"
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'session', // changed from token to session
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

I changed the driver of the api guard to `session`.

```
// In "app\Http\Kernel.php"
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
],
```

I added the middlewares to support cookies in the api middleware

```
// In "routes\api.php"
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

This is an example that comes with a new Laravel installation.

```
// In "app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php"
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    'prefix' => 'api',
], function ($router) {
    require base_path('routes/api.php');
});
```

The `api` middleware is applied to all the routes defined in the `api.php` file.

I want to be able to query my API after a user has logged in without using tokens, etc. The app I wrote with Laravel 5.2 had basically the same route but only the `web` middleware group and `auth` middleware applied to it. In Laravel 5.3, adding the `auth` middleware leads to the described problem.

**edit**: With my configuration I tried the following:

```
// In "routes\web.php"
Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
    return "test";
})->middleware(['auth']);
```

This works perfectly fine, but this doesn't, although the `web` and the `api` guard are exactly the same inside the `auth.php`.

```
Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
    return "test";
})->middleware(['auth:api']);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I'm using `auth` only for now on the api Route group. Couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work...

Comment: @Notflip fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040226/route-not-found-after-adding-authapi-middleware-laravel-5-3

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue of getting redirected to the `/home` while accessing my API routes even if I was already logged in.
Try changing the order of your api middlewares in `App\Http\Kernel.php` and place `bindings` in last position so your custom middlewares are executed first.

Comment: Thanks for this response - all I was missing was having the start session class before bindings!